# Use another theme template in my theme

Tags: customization, themes, templates, get-template-part

I want to use a different theme's portfolio page in my theme. I just want the content (portfolio layout of the other theme) but my own (active theme) header, footer, sidebar, and everything else. Is there a structured approach for this problem?

Comment: I don't think its possible but still see how experts respond to your query. But best way is to copy that template and related files , css , js into the theme you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create child theme of the main theme you're using. That way you can override just the parts you want. Reference - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Hope it helps!